# Changing factor levels-- unknown levels in "f" -- can't change levels

Tags: r, forcats

I have a factor containing many industry names. I need to collapse them into major categories and industries. For example, because I allowed respondents to respond with whatever they want, I have an inflated number of levels (e.g. financial services, Financial Services, Banking, Finance). Because these cases don't match, they come out as an additional level, so I'm trying to collapse them with forcats:

```
test <- fct_collapse(PrescreenF$Industry, Finance = c("Banking",
  "Corporate Finance", "Finance", "Financial", "financial services",
  "financial services", "Financial Services", "Financial services"),
  NULL = "H")
```

I get a warning that says: "Financial services" is unknown. This is extremely frustrating because when I call up the vector, I can see that it does exist. I've tried copying and pasting the exact words from the call, re-writing it and it just seems like there are hidden characters that prevent it from being changed.

How do I properly collapse these values?

```
-> test$industry
Banking
Corporate Finance 
Finance Financial 
financial services
financial services 
Financial Services 
Financial services
```

When I go to "revalue" say, the last level, "Financial services", it tells me its an unknown string.

**EDIT**
output of dput(x$industry)

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L
), .Label = c("", "{\"ImportId\":\"QID8_TEXT\"}", "Finance", 
"Financial ", "Financial services ", "Please indicate the industry you work in (e.g. technology, healthcare etc):", 
"Cleantech", "Delivery", "e-commerce/fashion", "Food", "Food & Bev", 
"Retail", "Service", "tech", "technology", "Technology", "IT, technology", 
"Software", "Technology ", "Tehcnology", "Consulting", "Digital advertising", 
"Education", "Higher education", "Technology, management consulting", 
"University professor; teaching, research and service", "Information Technology and Services", 
"mobile technology"), class = "factor")
```

EDIT
Figured it out. Some of the terms had an extra space after they ended. For example, although when I called Prescreen$Industry, it would return a number of names like "Banking" and "Corporate Finance", it didn't tell me that there was a space after the level. Banking was actually.. "Banking " with an invisible space that didn't show up in R. How does one go about making sure this is visible and doesn't happen again?

Can I run a len function within a column? If so, how does that work? 
PrescreenF$Industry("Banking")?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of your data so we can trouble shoot this.

Comment: if there are hidden characters, they are probably white space. `stringr::str_trim` could help, but you'd have to change the factors to character first, then back to factor.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dput(test$industry)` or of `dput(head(test, 20))`?

Comment: @RuiBarradas Just added a new edit section.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @shea Could you give me an example of how to use stringr and str_trim? If you can answer the question: "How do I properly assess the characters in a factor level? Then yes, it'll be the answer. 

For example,

When I call a summary(df), for factor Y it will display 4 levels: accounting, finance, banking, tech. When I attempt to change the levels name, it won't register that "accounting" is a valid string-- because its actually 
"accounting " with one white space. I've been figuring this out manually by adding spaces and trial and error when trying to slice it out.

Comment: I posted an answer that shows you how to load 'stringr '. The answer also has the steps for using 'str_trim'. You don't have to measure or count white space, 'str_trim' does it for you and cuts it out. You might want to look at ?str_trim. The answer is below these comments.

Comment: I'll study some stringr. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If "x" is your `dataframe`

```
library(stringr)

x$industry <- as.character(x$industry)
x$industry <- str_trim(x$industry)
x$industry <- as.factor(x$industry)
```

Then you can get back to `fct_collapse()` to simplify your factors.